# Software for creating thumbnail preview table of all photos in a folder

Tags: windows, images, image-viewer, thumbnail

Is there a Windows program that lets you arrange a batch of photos in a folder into an organized thumbnail preview table, but encapsulate to a 1:1 aspect ratio each thumbnail, and export that table as a stand-alone image?

Bonus points if it lets you re-position the 1:1 thumbnails individually. Plus the same question but for batch video .mp4 files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I. Irfan View. https://www.irfanview.com/**

I can not overstate how good this program is. It is fast, simple, but have a ton of options to customize without making it complex.

1. In Irfan View press "T" (This will open an additional program, Thumbnail viewer)
2. Select your folder and Choose the images you want. You can select them all (Ctrl+A)
   [image]
3. File > Create contact sheet from selected images
   [image]

Select the paper size (4) Resolution (5) Font for the info displayed (6) and output files. If you do not select an output file it will render in the main IrfanView window.

[image]

<sub>Images from Andrea Piacquadio</sub>

---

**II. You have a native option in Windows (10):**

1. Select your folder, and select some images.
2. Right click on one, and choose Print. A dialog box will appear:

Look for the option contact sheet.

[image]

**III. Some other options:**

Image Magick: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/montage.php

PhotoShop: https://helpx.adobe.com/nz/photoshop/how-to/create-contact-sheets.html

XnView: https://www.xnview.com/wiki/index.php/Contact_Sheet

Comment: Surprised that flagship image editors like Photoshop and Gimp don't have a dedicated batch thumbnail generator

Comment: Well, I posted a link for a contact sheet on Photoshop.

Comment: I updated the answer with some more options.

Comment: How about batch video .mp4 files

Comment: Well, you can always make a screen capture... :P

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use Explorer > View ?

[image]